# NHibernate returning wrong results of SQL query

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

I have a query which contains in the select clause:

```
    d1.id,
    d1.title,
    d1.original_doc,
    d2.id,
    d2.title
```

And in the from clause:

```
    left outer join documents d2 on d1.original_doc = d2.id
```

Let's say in the DB I have these rows:
        ID TITLE ORIGINAL_DOC

```
    1 Title1 
    2 Title2 1
```

For the first row, NHibernate will return 1, Title1, null, 1, Title1 instead of 1, Title1, null, null, null.

For the second row, it will return 2, Title2, 1, 2, Title2 instead of 2, Title2, 1, 1, Title1.

Note that the third and fourth column should not contain different values, as the condition of the join is them being the same. What seems to be happening is that I am getting the same d1 row joined as d2, instead of the row defined by the condition.

Now the weird part: **If I turn .ShowSql() on and copy-paste the query into Oracle Toad, it actually returns the correct results!**

I am getting the result set in NHibernate by using var data = session.CreateSQLQuery(selectQuery).List()

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reported [exactly this as a bug](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1576), but it's not a bug. NH manages the result internally using column names. If they have the same name, it picks the first. You need to give it unique names in the select clause:

```
SELECT
  d1.id as id1,
  d1.title as title1,
  d1.original_doc as original_doc1,
  d2.id as id2,
  d2.title as title2
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! That seems pretty weak from NHibernate, returning different results from what the DB would return when facing the exact same query. I would not even mind an error but stealthily returning wrong results is really bad. And it is not a necessary limitation at all. :/ When you think about it, this is clearly a bug.

Comment: This is my opinion too. You can put some comment in the jira if you want. It might be better to add a new issue of type "feature enhancement". Just be polite in the jira, some people are sensitive there ...

Comment: +1 for reporting the bug id which led me to conclude that this bug is "not a bug" for nhibernate and that I should rename column names with same spelling in my query.

Comment: How to live with this "not a bug"? My case is that the user give an input as sql and he  want correct result. Should I skip using nhibernate or something better? There is now way to override this implementation?

Comment: @user1785960: Well, I'm not sure if SQL is a appropriate interface. However, If it is really SQL, not HQL, you don't need NHibernate.